# How to use the SetEnvIf in this situation?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, setenv, x-frame-options

I try to put a X-FRAME-OPTIONS to the http header to prevent the Clickjacking attack. 
If I set the header in the httpd.conf or .htaccess file like this, it works.

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

But there are several places that using the iFrame on my own website, if I do this, it will also block the iFrame on my own website. So I try to add a exception for my own website. Check  if the request is from my own website, then allow the iFrame on the page. I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
SetEnvIf Host http://myownwebsite\.com iframes_are_cool
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN env=!iframes_are_cool
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: have you tried `SetEnvIf Host "^myownwebsite\.com$" iframes_are_cool` ?

Answer (score 0):

SetEnvIf is not as flexible so I recommend to use simply the // sections. Give the below a try:

```
<If "! %{HOST} =~ /http://myownwebsite\.com/">
  Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</If>
```